# How to wait for a thread to finish without high CPU load?

Tags: c++, multithreading, arm64, stdthread

I have a program that creates multiple working threads and then wait's for them to finish.
The code is equivalent to this:

The worker functions both contain infinite loops and do not finish during normal operation.

```cpp
void workerFunction1(void)
{
    while (true) {
        // do processing
    }
}

void workerFunction2(void)
{
    while (true) {
        // do processing
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::thread* workerThread1 = new std::thread(&workerFunction1);
    std::thread* workerThread2 = new std::thread(&workerFunction2);

    // Block main thread while worker functions run
    workerThread1.join();
    workerThread2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The program works fine, but in `htop` I noticed that one of my CPU cores has 100% load, caused by a single thread.
I printed out each threads TID using `syscall(SYS_gettid)` and compared them to the TIDs in htop. From that I concluded that it's the main thread that causes the extreme cpu load.

What's the preferred way to block the main thread while the worker functions still run? (they run for a looong time, but may finish if there's an error)

Comment: `join` should not be active wait in reasonable implementations, what stdlib are you using?

Comment: Are you sure ? As far as I know common impelementations for `join` do **not** busy wait.

Comment: I think the problem is not in your join, but in the work done on your threads. You should be able to terminate your infinite loops to shut down your program (ideally use std::condition_variable/mutex/value combination to break out of the loop, cooperative termination)

Comment: How exactly you conclude that the 100% cpu load is due to join? I don't understand how `syscall(SYS_gettid)` helps you with that. It is more than likely that these spawned workers are causing that.

Comment: @freakish My bad, I should have elaborated on that. In `htop`, I can see all the programs threads, their cpu load and their TID. I then printed out the TID in the program in each thread using syscall and it was the main thread that has 100% cpu load.

Comment: without knowing what the workerfunctions do we can only guess ... is it meant as contest of guessing or question?

Comment: @Zciurus htop will show you info based on parent/child relationship. Meaning the main thread uses 100%, out of which thread 1 uses X, while thread 2 uses Y. It doesn't mean that the main thread does any job. It means all of its children and itself creates the 100% load.

Comment: @freakish I didn't know that, thanks for the info. I switched to tree view in htop, but the cpu% don't seem to add up. The parent process has 100% cpu load, but the threads only have like 5% together.

Comment: @Zciurus can you paste the real htop output (only the process with all its threads and subprocesses) and the command you use? Just to be 100% sure that you didn't miss anything. Because that looks weird.

Comment: @freakish Here's the htop output https://pastebin.com/dg2CLydJ , the relevant part is `my-program` at the bottom

Comment: @Zciurus your main thread runs for a long period (6 minutes) while child threads live for a very short time. Htop gathers data from a time window, I think it is 3s by default. So if a thread spawns and exits during that window, its work will get accumulated to its parent, but it won't be shown in htop (since it doesn't exist anymore). Does this scenario look like as a reasonable explanation to you? I suggest utilizing a thread pool, instead of spawning threads. Since thread pool threads live long, it will also help with proper htop analysis.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for the explaination, I found my problem. The main issue was that I was searching for the problem in the main thread when it was a problem in one of the worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake, the high CPU load had nothing to do with `.join()`. It was an issue in one of the worker threads, but since I didn't know about the parent/child relationship in `htop`, I misinterpeted it as an issue with the main program.

The problematic worker function also had a very short loop cycle, which I assume is the reason htop wasn't able to assign the cpu load to that specific thread while still adding it to the parent program.